# Reference suggestion for algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

I want to do a self study algebra, but don't know what would be a good source to start with. I have a few in my mind:

- Artin, Algebra
- Dummit & Foote, Abstract Algebra

Is there anyone who could compare books above? I am also open for any suggestions! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Edit the question to tell us a little about your background, as the linked possible duplicate from @Watson does. You'll get better advice that way.

Comment: Dummit & Foote is what I used. Lots of exercises and lots of good explanatory passages. Solutions to exercises are lacking but can be found easily online.